# Premature close with pipeline, but not if using pipe

Tags: javascript, node.js, pipe, pipeline

Here's a problem I can't get my head around.

This works:

```
let readStream = fs.createReadStream(imgPath);
let imageMagicStream = spawn('convert', ['-', '-resize', '750', '-'], { env: env });
let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(out);

readStream.pipe(imageMagicStream.stdin);
imageMagicStream.stdout.pipe(writeStream);
```

However, if I try to use pipeline instead, I get 'Error [ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE]: Premature close':

```
let readStream = fs.createReadStream(imgPath);
let imageMagicStream = spawn('convert', ['-', '-resize', '750', '-'], { env: env });
let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(out);

pipeline(readStream, imageMagicStream.stdin, writeStream, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

It appears writeStream is closing early. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

**FOLLOW UP ANSWER:**

Thank you for Bergi's answer. I found a package (npm i duplexer) that lets you create a duplex stream easily. My code now looks something like this:

```
const { pipeline } = require("stream");
const duplexer = require('duplexer');

async function resizeImg(imgPath, out) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        let readStream = fs.createReadStream(imgPath);
        let imageMagicStream = spawn('magick', ['convert', '-', '-resize', '750', '-'], { env: env });
        let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(out);

        let duplexStreams = duplexer(imageMagicStream.stdin, imageMagicStream.stdout);

        await pipeline(readStream, duplexStreams, writeStream, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return reject(err);
            }
        });

        return resolve();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pipeline` function](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback) requires a *transform stream* for the middle argument(s), a stream that is both writable and readable. Notice your original code made *two* `.pipe()` calls, one into the `stdin` and one from the `stdout`, but your second snippet does only use `stdin`. You'd have to write

```
function logError(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
pipeline(readStream, imageMagicStream.stdin, logError);
pipeline(imageMagicStream.stdout, writeStream, logErrr);
```

You might also be able to construct a duplex stream from the `stdin` and `stdout` of the child process, but this seems unnecessarily complicated.